# Xamarin iOS throws System.TypeInitializationException when loading a large native library

Tags: exception, xamarin.ios

I have an iOS app built with Xamarin iOS that crashes when loading the class that has DllImport attributes for PInvoke calls. The exception is:

```
Unhandled managed exception: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE (System.TypeInitializationException)
```

The app worked fine, but started crashing when the native library grew in size. After cropping some parts of the library it worked again, but after linking a new library it started crashing again. The crash happens before any calls are actually made to the native library.

Here is the device log after the crash: http://pastebin.com/vW3CMXHq

The inner exceptions are:

```
Aug 23 10:33:40 Outboxs-iPod pazanga[4216] <Warning>: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for SWIGStringHelper ---> System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper native-to-managed) Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE/SWIGStringHelper:CreateString (intptr)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
at (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_to_ftnptr (object)
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE/SWIGStringHelper:SWIGRegisterStringCallback_Zz (Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE/SWIGStringHelper/SWIGStringDelegate)
at Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE+SWIGStringHelper..cctor () [0x00017] in /Users/max/Code/pazanga/mobile/ios/bindings/ZzPINVOKE.cs:229
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE..cctor () [0x0000a] in /Users/max/Code/pazanga/mobile/ios/bindings/ZzPINVOKE.cs:233
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Pazanga.Native.Zz.locate (System.Byte[] image, image_format format, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 x, Int32 y) [0x00009] in /Users/max/Code/pazanga/mobile/ios/bindings/Zz.cs:16
at Pazanga.CaptureDecode.ProcessFrame (System.Byte[] data, Int32 dataWidth, Int32 dataHeight, Boolean isPicture) [0x000cf] in /Users/max/Code/pazanga/mobile/common/CaptureDecode.cs:95
at Pazanga.iOS.CaptureViewController.HandleNewFrame (System.Byte[] data, Int32 width, Int32 height) [0x0003b] in /Users/max/Code/pazanga/mobile/ios/App/CaptureViewController.cs:128
at Pazanga.iOS.CaptureManager.OnNewFrame (System.Byte[] array, Int32 width, Int32 height) [0x00015] in /Users/max/Code/pazanga/mobile/ios/App/CaptureManager.cs:126
at Pazanga.iOS.CaptureManager+OutputDelegate.DidOutputSampleBuffer (MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVCaptureOutput captureOutput, MonoTouch.CoreMedia.CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer, MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVCaptureConnection connection) [0x000c6] in /Users/max/Code/pazanga/mobile/ios/App/CaptureManager.cs:110
Aug 23 10:33:40 Outboxs-iPod pazanga[4216] <Warning>: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for SWIGStringHelper ---> System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper native-to-managed) Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE/SWIGStringHelper:CreateString (intptr)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
at (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_to_ftnptr (object)
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE/SWIGStringHelper:SWIGRegisterStringCallback_Zz (Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE/SWIGStringHelper/SWIGStringDelegate)
at Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE+SWIGStringHelper..cctor () [0x00017] in /Users/max/Code/pazanga/mobile/ios/bindings/ZzPINVOKE.cs:229
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE..cctor () [0x0000a] in /Users/max/Code/pazanga/mobile/ios/bindings/ZzPINVOKE.cs:233
Aug 23 10:33:40 Outboxs-iPod pazanga[4216] <Warning>: System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper native-to-managed) Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE/SWIGStringHelper:CreateString (intptr)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
at (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_to_ftnptr (object)
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE/SWIGStringHelper:SWIGRegisterStringCallback_Zz (Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE/SWIGStringHelper/SWIGStringDelegate)
at Pazanga.Native.ZzPINVOKE+SWIGStringHelper..cctor () [0x00017] in /Users/max/Code/pazanga/mobile/ios/bindings/ZzPINVOKE.cs:229
```

And here is the SWIGStringHelper class (generated by SWIG) that appears in the exception:

```
protected class SWIGStringHelper {

  public delegate string SWIGStringDelegate(string message);   
  static SWIGStringDelegate stringDelegate = new SWIGStringDelegate(CreateString);

  [DllImport("__Internal", EntryPoint="SWIGRegisterStringCallback_Zz")]   
  public static extern void SWIGRegisterStringCallback_Zz(SWIGStringDelegate stringDelegate);

  [MonoTouch.MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(SWIGStringDelegate))]
  static string CreateString(string cString) {
    return cString;   
  }

  static SWIGStringHelper() {
    SWIGRegisterStringCallback_Zz(stringDelegate);   
  } 
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Please post the complete output in the Application Output and/or Device Log from Xamarin Studio. You can probably print a better message by adding a try/catch handler in your Main method, which will catch this exception (and you can iterate over InnerExceptions until you reach the original exception).

Comment: Thanks @RolfBjarneKvinge! I added the device log. I couldn't catch the exception with a try/catch in Main, it didn't print anything from the handler, and a breakpoint didn't work either.

Comment: The try/catch in Main didn't work because you're not crashing in the main thread, so Main isn't in the stack. Try adding a try/catch in one of the methods in the stack trace you get (OutputDelegate.DidOutputSampleBuffer [...] in [...]/CaptureManager.cs:111 for instance)

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge Thanks again. I catched the exception, and it mentions problems with the aot compiler. But I didn't find anything on the limitations doc that could cause the problem. It also is strange that seemingly unrelated changes to the native library cause the crash.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you file a bug with a test project here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com?

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge Done, it's bug number 14242

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close the loop... It turned out to be a duplicate of [bug 14194](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=14194) (reverse callback using a string).

A `TypeInitializationException` was thrown because the exception occurred inside a static constructor.